# How to show an image in template uploaded from admin panel Django 1.3

Tags: django, django-1.3

I'm a newbie to django. I'm developing a project in django 1.3. Problem is I'm uploading a image from the admin panel

```
class About(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='about')
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='about')
```

Here is my template tag

```
<img class="profile_pic" src="{{ about.image }}" />
```

My setting file is as below

```
MEDIA_ROOT = path("media/")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    path('static/'),
)
```

I checked that image is uploaded to /media/about/image_name. Problem is it rendered in the template as "/about/imagename" but not shoing. When I manually go to that image url it showing a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked!... After importing setting.MEDIA_ROOT in the urls.py file then I added a media rule so ITs working now..

BTW It also need

```
{{ about.image.url }}
```

as @zsquare(thanks) said earlier Here is the media rule

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Comment: Kinda forgot about that possibility.

Comment: Your solution would work, but its not a good idea to serve media from django. Apache, etc are much better suited for that. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

`<img class="profile_pic" src="{{ about.image.url }}" />`

UPDATE

Also in your urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
```

Comment: nope! not working. But the image is now showing the path which should be ok. Should I use any url rule for media folder?