# Images not showing on Django App

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner trying to work through this tutorial from lightbird.net to build a photo sharing app.  I'm having a problem getting photos to display on the development server.  While I can upload and save images on the admin interface, the photos also don't display there.  Instead, a jpeg icon is all I see.  When I view the page on the development server, the same jpeg icon appears rather than the photo.

It took me awhile to get PIL and jpeg library installed yesterday and while my app runs without errors now, I suspect the reason the images dont display has to do with one of those two installations.  I thought it might be a browser issue, but i cant view the images from firefox, google chrome or safari.

Thanks in advance for the help. This site rocks!

The html for the code is :

```
{% extends "pbase.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="main">
        <!-- Albums -->
        <ul>
            {% for album in albums.object_list %}
                <div class="title">{{ album.title }} ({{ album.image_set.count}} images)</div>
                <ul>
                    {% for img in album.images %}
                        <a href="{{ media_url }}{{ img.image.name }}"><img border="0" alt="" 
                            src="{{ media_url }}{{ img.thumbnail2.name }}" /></a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <!--Next/Prev page links-->
        {% if albums.object_list and albums.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="step-links">
                {% if albums.has_previous %}
                    <a href= "?page={{ albums.previous_page_number }}">previous &lt;&lt;</a>
                {% endif %}

                <span class="current"> 
                    &nbsp;Page {{ albums.number }} of {{ albums.paginator.num_pages }}
                </span>
                {% if albums.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ albums.next_page_number }}"> &gt;&gt; next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The view is :

```
def main(request):
    albums = Album.objects.all()
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        albums = albums.filter(public=True)

    paginator = Paginator(albums, 10)
    try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", "1"))
    except ValueError: page = 1

    try:
        albums = paginator.page(page)
    except(InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        albums = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    for album in albums.object_list:
        album.images = album.image_set.all()[:4]

    return render_to_response("list.html", {'albums':albums, 'user':request.user, 'media_url':MEDIA_URL})
```

And my models are:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def images(self):
        lst = [x.image.name for x in self.image_set.all()]
        lst = ["<a href='/media/%s'>%s</a>" % (x, x.split("/")[-1])for x in lst]
        return join(lst, ",")
    images.allow_tags = True


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag


class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True) 
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """save image dimensions."""
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        im = PImage.open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
        self.width, self.height = im.size

        # large thumb
        fn, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image.name)
        im.thumbnail((128,128), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb2" + ext
        tf2 = NamedTemporaryFile()
        im.save(tf2.name, "JPEG")
        self.thumbnail2.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf2.name)), save=False)
        tf2.close()

        #small thumb
        im.thumbnail((40,40), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_fn = fn + "-thumb" + ext
        tf = NamedTemporaryFile()
        im.save(tf.name, "JPEG")
        self.thumbnail2.save(thumb_fn, File(open(tf.name)), save=False)
        tf.close()

        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    

    def size(self):
        return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)

    def tags_(self):
        lst = [x[1] for x in self.tags.values_list()]
        return str(join(lst, ', '))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name

    def albums_(self):
        lst = [x[1] for x in self.albums.values_list()]
        return str(join(lst, ', '))

    def thumbnail(self):
        return """<a href="/media/%s"><img border="0" alt="" src="/media%s" height="40" /></a>""" % (self.image.name, self.image.name)
    thumbnail.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{img.image.url}}` to get absolute url of your image field.
I hope you have referred
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

[How do I include image files in Django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates)

[How to show an image in template uploaded from admin panel Django 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800166/how-to-show-an-image-in-template-uploaded-from-admin-panel-django-1-3)

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to update your projects urls.py with the following:

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
```